# How can I increase product names length in pdf?

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf

**Magento version 1.9** and in `pdf` I want to increase the **length of product name** please give me the solutions.
Please share path of `pdf` where we need to do changes

This is the link of our web site

> http://youstorehk.aquaspade.cloud/

---

[image]

i am using Magento 1.9 ver need to increase product name length in pdf

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify product name in **invoice** `pdf`, just **override** below file to your **local**. Modify if you are not using other **3rd party extension** related to **sales order**.

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php

Comment: which file need to override?

Comment: follow link: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/

Comment: thank you, but want exact file location we have to change length of product characters 32 to 40 characters.

Comment: Here we can not set characters length, just manage text decoration feature like bold, font size increase/decrease etc. Yes, you can decrease font size so your text fitted into a width that is one solution for your current issue.